# Error: QQmlApplicationEngine failed to load component "Network problem"

Tags: python, qml, pyside6

I'm new to qml and python This is the code and error I get:

Error:

```
QQmlApplicationEngine failed to load component
c:%5CUsers%5Cpcmcb%5COneDrive%5CDesktop%5Capp%5Capp%5Cqml/main.qml: Network error
```

main.py:

```
mport sys
import os

from PySide6.QtGui import QGuiApplication
from PySide6.QtQml import QQmlApplicationEngine


if __name__ == "__main__":
app = QGuiApplication(sys.argv)
engine = QQmlApplicationEngine()
engine.load(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "qml/main.qml"))


if not engine.rootObjects():
    sys.exit(-1)
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

main.qml:

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Window 2.15
import QtQuick.Controls 2.15
import QtQuick.Controls.Material 2.15

ApplicationWindow{
    id: window
    width: 400
    height: 580
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("Login Page")
}
```

When I try to run the code it gives me the error that I typed above

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`load()` method requires a QUrl so passing it a string can cause problems, change to:

```py
import os
from pathlib import Path
import sys

from PySide6.QtCore import QCoreApplication, Qt, QUrl
from PySide6.QtGui import QGuiApplication
from PySide6.QtQml import QQmlApplicationEngine

CURRENT_DIRECTORY = Path(__file__).resolve().parent


def main():
    app = QGuiApplication(sys.argv)

    engine = QQmlApplicationEngine()

    filename = os.fspath(CURRENT_DIRECTORY / "qml" / "main.qml")
    url = QUrl.fromLocalFile(filename)

    def handle_object_created(obj, obj_url):
        if obj is None and url == obj_url:
            QCoreApplication.exit(-1)

    engine.objectCreated.connect(handle_object_created, Qt.QueuedConnection)
    engine.load(url)

    sys.exit(app.exec())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```